# dynamic styles in styled-jsx not behaving as expected

Tags: next.js, styled-jsx

The variables I set (bgColor,txtColor) don't consistently make it into the styled-jsx.  I've attached a screen shot where you can see the console.log isn't showing the same values that are being rendered.

I believe there is something about styled-jsx that I'm not getting.  Not sure why this isn't working.

```
const Badge = (props) => {
  const { variation = null, size = null } = props;

  let bgColor = "#eeeeee";
  let txtColor = "#000000";
  switch (variation) {
    case "red":
      bgColor = "#FADBD8";
      txtColor = "red";
      break;
    case "green":
      bgColor = "#D5F5E3";
      txtColor = "green";
      break;
  }
  /* Test to see what our values are */
  console.log(`props.children=${props.children}, bgColor=${bgColor}, txtColor=${txtColor}`)
  return (
    <span className="badge">
      {props.children}

      {/* My colors and text in the CSS do not match the vars printed to cosole above */}
      <style jsx>{`
        .badge {
          text-transform: capitalize;
          display: inline-block;
          padding: 0.2rem 0.4rem;
          border-radius: 3px;
          background-color: ${bgColor};
          color: ${txtColor};  
        }

      `}</style>
    </span>
  );
};
```

Here is an example of a goofed up rendering of the component...
[image]

**Update**
Have dug deeper.  It looks like sometimes it is assigning the same generated JSX style to items that should be different colors.  Any thoughts on why it would assign it the same class?  (img attached)
[image]

Comment: If i updated the code and the page re-renders the colors and variables seem to be in sync, if i just refresh the page things goof up.  Maybe that helps identify what is going on here?

Comment: Maybe you should use `f12` to check whether other styles rewrite your `jsx style`.

Comment: other styles aren't rewriting it.  will post an image.  it is coming from the jsx classes

Comment: I think there is something to it working when the page re-renders itself vs a hard refresh.  Can client and server get out of sync or something?  This is my first nextjs project and have been fighting with this bug for hours now.

Comment: When refreshing I'm getting this error... "Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "Low" Client: "High"... that help?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is out of sync between render styles in server and client. You can apply `useState` to solve the problem.

```
const [bgColor, setBgColor] = useState('#eeeeee')

switch(variation) {
  case 'red':
    setBgColor('#FADBD8')
    break
  case 'green'
    setBgColor('#D5F5E3')
    break
}
```